# Securing the route on OPENSHIFT

Tags: docker, authentication, oauth, cloud, openshift

I deployed an Application on OPENSHIFT. And created a route for it. I want the route to be accessible by only few users and not everyone. And the users who can access the route should be controlled by me. It's like providing Authentication Scheme for the route in the Openshift. How can i achieve this. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OpenShift Routes do not have any authentication mechanisms built-in. There are the usual TLS / subdomain / path-based routing features, but no authentication.

So your most straight-forward path on OpenShift would be to deploy an additional reverse proxy as part of your application such as "nginx", "traefik" or "haproxy":

```
                       +-------------+       +-----------------+
                       |   reverse   |       |                 |
+--incoming traffic--->+   proxy     +------>+ your application|
   from your Route     |             |       |                 |
                       +-------------+       +-----------------+
```

For authentication methods, you then have multiple options, depending on which solution you choose to deploy (the simplest ones being Basic Auth or Digest Auth).

Answer (score 1):

While Kubernetes ingress controllers usually embeds such functionality, this is not the case with OpenShift. The recommended way would usually be to rely on an oauth-proxy, which would integrate with the OpenShift API, allowing for easy integration with OpenShift users -- while it could also be used integrating with third-party providers (KeyCloak, LemonLDAP-NG, ...).

#### Oauth

Integrating with the OpenShift API, we would first create a `ServiceAccount`, such as the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.my-app: '{"kind":"OAuthRedirectReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"Route","name":"my-route-name"}}'
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-project
```

That annotation would tell OpenShift how to send your users back to your application, upon successful login: look for a Route `my-route-name`.

We will also create a certificate, signed by OpenShift PKI, that we'll later use setting up our OAuth proxy. This could be done creating a `Service` such as the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name: my-app-tls
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-project
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8443
    name: oauth
  selector:
    [ your deployment selector placeholder ]
```

We may then add a sidecar container into our application deployment:

```
[...]
containers:
- args:
  - -provider=openshift
  - -proxy-prefix=/oauth2
  - -skip-auth-regex=^/public/
  - -login-url=https://console.example.com/oauth/authorize
  - -redeem-url=https://kubernetes.default.svc/oauth/token
  - -https-address=:8443
  - -http-address=
  - -email-domain=*
  - -upstream=http://localhost:3000
  - -tls-cert=/etc/tls/private/tls.crt
  - -tls-key=/etc/tls/private/tls.key
  - -client-id=system:serviceaccount:my-project:my-app
  - -client-secret-file=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
  - -cookie-refresh=0
  - -cookie-expire=24h0m0s
  - -cookie-name=_oauth2_mycookiename
  name: oauth-proxy
  image: docker.io/openshift/oauth-proxy:latest
  [ resource requests/limits & livenesss/readiness placeholder ]
  volumeMounts:
  - name: cert
    path: /etc/tls/private
 [ your application container placeholder ]
 serviceAccount: my-app
 serviceAccountName: my-app
 volumes:
 - secret:
     name: my-app-tls
   name: cert
```

Assuming:

- `console.example.com` your OpenShift public API FQDN
- `^/public/`, optional path regexpr that should not be subject to authentication
- `http://localhost:3000`, the URL the Oauth proxy would connect, fix port to whichever your application binds to. Also consider reconfiguring your application to bind on its loopback interface only, preventing accesses that would bypass your oauth proxy
- `my-project` / `my-app`, your project & app names

Make sure your `Route` tls termination is set to Passthrough, sends its traffic to port `8443`.

Checkout https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy for an exhaustive list of options. the `openshift-sar` one could be interesting, filtering which users may log in, based on their permissions over OpenShift objects.

Obviously, in some cases you would be deploying applications that could be configured to integrate with some OAuth provider: then there's no reason to use a proxy.

#### Basic Auth

In cases you do not want to integrate with OpenShift users, nor any kind of third-party provider, you may want to use some nginx sidecar container - there are plenty available on dockerhub.

#### Custom Ingress

Also note that with OpenShift 3.x, cluster admins may customize the template used to generate HAProxy configuration, patching their ingress deployment. This is a relatively common way to fix some headers, handle some custom annotations for your users to set in their `Routes`, ... Look for `TEMPLATE_FILE` in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#env-variables.

As of right now, I do not think OpenShift 4 ingress controllers would allow for this - as it is driven by an operator, with limited configuration options, see https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/ingress-operator.html.

Although as for OpenShift 3: you may very well deploy your own ingress controllers, should you have to handle such edge cases.

Comment: any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040017/securing-path-based-routing-on-openshift