# Securing path based routing on Openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, oauth-2.0, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

My application deployed on openshift has url as https://host:port/app/v1/hello/
I am using ServiceAccount as Oauth client and the provider is Openshift, so I should be redirected to Openshift login page for Authorization.

We have configured openshift/oauth-proxy and it works great.
https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy/

Now further we have requirement of Path based routing, like if URL has /app/v1 then redirect to Service1 and if /app/v2 then to Service2

Here is the working example of my configuration,

```
`kind: Template
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: deployment-template
objects:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: my-service-account
      annotations:
        serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.first: '{"kind":"OAuthRedirectReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"Route","name":"my-route"}}'
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: my-service
      annotations:
        service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name: proxy-tls
    spec:
      selector:
        app: spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world
      ports:
        - name: api
          protocol: TCP
          port: 443 #Port the service listens on.
          targetPort: 8443 #Port on the backing pods to which the service forwards connections.
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: my-route
    spec:
      port:
        targetPort: api
      path: "/"
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: my-service
      tls:
        termination: Reencrypt
  - apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
    kind: DeploymentConfig
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world
        version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.1.dev
      name: spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        app: spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world
      strategy:
        rollingParams:
          timeoutSeconds: 3600
        type: Rolling
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world
            version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.1.dev
        spec:
          serviceAccount: my-service-account
          serviceAccountName: my-service-account
          containers:
          - name: spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world
            env:
              - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            image: pokarjm/spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.1.dev
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            securityContext:
              privileged: false
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8080
                protocol: TCP
          - name: oauth-proxy
            image: openshift/oauth-proxy:latest
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8443
                name: public
            args:
              - --https-address=:8443
              - --provider=openshift
              - --openshift-service-account=my-service-account
              - --upstream=http://localhost:8080
              - --tls-cert=/etc/tls/private/tls.crt
              - --tls-key=/etc/tls/private/tls.key
              - --cookie-secret-file=/etc/proxy/secret/session_secret
              - --openshift-ca=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
              - --openshift-sar={"namespace":"spring-boot-docker-openshift-hello-world","resource":"services","name":"my-service","verb":"get"}
              - --request-logging=true
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /etc/tls/private
                name: proxy-tls
                readOnly: true
              - mountPath: /etc/proxy/secret
                name: oauth-proxy-secret
                readOnly: true
          volumes:
            - name: proxy-tls
              secret:
                defaultMode: 420
                secretName: proxy-tls
            - name: oauth-proxy-secret
              secret:
                defaultMode: 420
                secretName: oauth-proxy-secret
      triggers:
        - type: ConfigChange
`
```

Now to support path based routing, that is map the request /app/v1 to Service1, I just added the Path in route like below,

```
- apiVersion: v1
    kind: Route
    metadata:
      name: my-route
    spec:
      port:
        targetPort: api
      path: "/app/v1"
      to:
        kind: Service
        name: my-service
      tls:
        termination: Reencrypt
```

but with this changes I can see a initial sign in page like below
[image]

but after clicking the button above instead of getting the openshift login page, I see below,

[image]

If I change the path in route to path: "/" it works and shows login screen.
Appreciate any help on fixing path based routing in openshift/oauth-proxy.

Comment: This could be helpful https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/12/12/securing-kubernetes-applications-with-openshift-oauth-proxy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding something like `--proxy-prefix=/app/v1`, to your oauth proxy container.

Eg:

```
[...]
        args:
          - --https-address=:8443
          - --provider=openshift
          - --proxy-prefix=/app/v1
          - --openshift-service-account=my-service-account
[...]
```

Otherwise, the oauth-proxy would assume the application it is serving lies at the root of your Route, breaking the login callback redirection.

---

Now, regarding your question in comments, I'm no sure I got it all myself, I don't have an OpenShift cluster to test this with, ... take it with a pinch of salt, edits welcome, if anyone can get this right.

As far as I understand and recall:

- Client connect to your app, going through your oauth-proxy.
- The proxy sees your client is unauthenticated and requests a token from the Oauth portal, using its client ID and secret (having set `openshift-service-account`, reads those out of `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/`). You could instead use `client-id=system:serviceaccount:$ns:$sa` and `client-secret-file=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`, if detection somehow doesn't work.
- The Oauth SP checks for our ServiceAccount with an `serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference` [annotation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/authentication/using-service-accounts-as-oauth-client.html) (though there's another way to do this, with [OauthClient](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html#oauth-register-additional-client_configuring-internal-oauth), which I'm less familiar with), matching the client requested application URL. On successful match, SP replies to oauth-proxy with some ephemeral token
- Knowing that token, and the `proxy-prefix`, the oauth-proxy redirects unauthenticated users to the Oauth login portal, with some encoded callback URL as a GET param
- User logs in against OpenShift users base
- On successful login, the Oauth Portal redirects you to the oauth-proxy, using the callback URL it received from your proxy
- the oauth-proxy redeems its token
- If `openshift-sar` was defined, oauth-proxy proceeds with some additional check ensuring client is authorized, otherwise any user may log in
- User optionally consent in granting some permissions

In OpenShift context, the initial token requests is done using the `login-url` param, which defaults to `kubernetes.default.svc/oauth/authorize`, though in some cases (not sure to remember, some unusual networkpolicies), you may want to force use your OpenShift console FQDN instead.

The token redemption is done through the `redeem-url` which defaults to `kubernetes.default.svc/oauth/token`. Again, you could use your public console FQDN here, if SDN otherwise denies this traffic.

*So*, how is proxy-prefix coming into the picture: only required for your oauth-proxy to build the proper callback URL, for the login form to send you back to the proper sub-path of your application.

And the OAuthRedirectReference is mainly used by OpenShift making sure the client requesting a token is indeed meant to authenticated clients for a given Route. In your case, only matching a FQDN, although I think that in addition to `serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.$name: {"kind": ...}`, you may also set something like `serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirecturi.name: my-path`

Comment: what i am missing here is the flow, could you please help me understand how the request flows here.
I made a request say https://host:port/context/v1, this goes to Route which is configured via path /context/v1 and it redirects to corresponding Service which in turn to Oauth proxy. proxy has --openshift-sar configured, so it redirects to openshift provider login page using the serviceAccount configured. how is proxy-prefix and service account OAuthRedirectReference coming into picture? could you please help @SYN

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate detailed explanation.

Comment: how can i make a HTTP POST request using this approach(say from tool like Postman) or through java client? I tried and what it returns is html data containing login page. I understand we need to use --openshift-delegate-urls for delegating authentication/authorization to master and also it requires cluster-admin role to be given to service account which is not possible in my case. wondering if there is any workaround that will help me do a HTTP POST request.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you want to integrate with OpenShift authentication without using the oauth-proxy, I see Postman documents OAuth login over there: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#oauth-20. Is this what you meant? Meanwhile, I don't think your ServiceAccount needs cluster-admin privileges, nor any specific RoleBinding whatsoever.

Comment: I tried setting up Postman to work with openshift-oauth-proxy and I am good. Thanks @SYN

Comment: do you know any work around on how to do service level testing where we don't want to go through Oauth UI flow, when openshift/oauth proxy in place, it seems one requires to give service account a system:auth-delegator access which requires cluster level permissions and seems difficult. section described here https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy#delegate-authentication-and-authorization-to-openshift-for-infrastructure, many are asking the same question(https://groups.google.com/g/aerogear/c/ex852iU9-iM/m/_zPYaowMAQAJ?pli=1), wondering if you came across such case and solved some way.

Comment: FYI, you may federate metrics out of Prometheus, going through its oauth-proxy, using a ServiceAccount with enough privileges to match their openshift-sar. So in a way, you may already bypass the "regular" oauth flow, authenticating with a Bearer Token (either from your ServiceAccount token Secrets, or out of `oc whoami -t` for Users). Then, no need to grant additional privileges to your oauth-proxy SA. Though I'm not familiar with the options discussed in that thread.